# Is this scenario an efficient way of generating electricity?

Tags: electricity, energy, mechanical

I will try my best in order to provide information which could help you imagine the scenario. Accurate results are not compulsory.

I am generating electricity using a 5kW alternator but for the electricity to be generated a weight of about 35 kg needs to be lifted for about 1 meter from the base level. In order to lift the weight I have applied a hydraulics system and the lever of the hydraulic is made to oscillate (i.e up and down) using a motor. A super capacitor is installed such that the the electricity generated is used to charge the capacitor each time it gets discharged. The super capacitor is used to run the motor in order to lift the weight.

What will be the efficiency of this system?

Is there any way we can increase the efficiency of the system?

Is there any alternate way to do the following tasks?

Please let me know if more information needed.

Comment: Wow, if you want the full 5kW from the alternator the weight needs to be lifted 15 times a second. Average velocity will be about 15 m/s. Are you sure this is feasible?

Comment: well one could use a gear box

Comment: What is the initial power source? Why won't the electricity be generated without lifting the weight? At the moment it's very unclear and sounds like a perpetual motion machine, for which the answer is: 0%. It won't work.

Comment: I could only say that the alternator is suspended at some height and a load is used to rotate the rotor part so the driving force is gravity

Comment: Why do you say this: *Lets deal this question as a brain storming session* - this is a question and answer site - if you need a talking shop or forum this isn't the place.

Comment: don't get offended i didn't meant it my english is a little weak

Comment: No, not efficient, you'll lose power. Lowering of the weight won't make enough energy to pull it back up.

Comment: I could not reveal the way by which i am rotating the rotor. Suppose that no energy is required to rotate it. And please help me with the scenario as given in the question above

Comment: @Tank12 I suggest you look at the new contributor's [site tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) - this explains the sort of questions which are suitable for this site. While some information could be provided you are not going 
 to get a satisfactory answer if part of the "problem" is 'a mystery'. It's up to you what you tell us, but at present this question is liable to be closed as being unsuited to this site. Questions can be reopened if they are edited to suit the site.

Comment: The system that you have described appears to be what is referred to as a "perpetual motion machine". Neil_UK has covered this well in his answer but a summary may be useful. If there is no external source of energy input then it will at best run for a while getting slower and slower and then stop. If any energy is taken out of the system it will stop more quickly. At each step in the process some energy is lost. The task could be done "better" by using thicker shorter wires, optimising motor efficicncy and hydraulic lift efficiency etc

Comment: ... BUT in all cases some energy will be lost at each step - without energy input it will cease operating and it is not suitable as a source of "free energy". [I proposed something like this when I was 11 years old - nobody then could explain to me why it wouldn't work :-(.

Comment: Wow @RussellMcMahon - you were inventing perpetual motion machines at that age? How old are you now?? ;)

Comment: @brhans I would be surprised if most engineers were not inventing perpetual motion machines when they were youngsters, I certainly was. I had a large open space park close to us, and I could visualise huge gear-wheels laid out in this park, a step-up gearing of course (once I had discovered them at the age of 8 or so) getting faster with each meshing gear, and tapping off the limitless energy from the fastest pinion. My only confusion was why this wasn't being done already! Sigh!

Comment: @brhans  111 -> 11 :-). [I'm 69 years young](http://bit.ly/oldgreyguy). My idea (paper only) was to use a vacuum cleaner motor (as I had such available) driving an alternator with a step up transformer to increase the voltage and then use a portion of the voltage to drive the motor. It "seemed likely" that it wouldn't work but I couldn't see why. The concept of conservation of energy not matching non conservation of voltage had not yet been encountered. My teacher said he believed it would not work BUT was unable to explain why. [I was at that School from about 10.1 - 11.9 years old.]

Comment: @Russell McMahon well in your case for the first time when electricity is given to the motor it will rotate the rotor but some energy will be lost due to friction then even if you increase the voltage then also some energy will be lost and same in case of the alternator and when this process is followed in iteration a time will come when the electricity provided by the motor will not be sufficient to run the motor. But if you have read the above question properly the you would not have given such lame example and by listening to others comment state my system as a perpetual machine.

Comment: @tank12 I explained in detail what was required to make the system work. I commented on efficiency improvements. I noted that " ... without energy input it will cease operating ." -> I don't know why you felt the need to be rude in response. I and others are trying to help. You have 5 downvotes and 3 close votes so far (NONE from me) . This site is an immensely valuable resource. It's not hard to fit in and answer people's questions when they try to help you. Being rude to helpers is a good way of never getting the value that the site can give you. Your choice.

Comment: Sorry for the above comment @Russel McMahon but no one is reading my question properly the thing which I want to ask is that if we consider a hypothetical situation where lifting of weight is doing the part of rotating the rotor and lifting is compulsory the go to my question and read again. I hope that this makes any sense

Comment: @tank12 It doesn't make any more sense. For one thing you have a generator and a motor, both of which have rotors, so when you say "the rotor" nobody knows what you mean. Also "the go to my question" ... what is this? You 'll need a clear drawing showing an external power input to this "system" before you can expect any help.

Answer (score 6):

Lifting a 35 kg =~ 350 N weight through 1m stores 350 Joules.

350 Joules will run a 5 kW alternator for about 350/5000 = 70 mS. This is not a suitable sized energy store for your generator.

Each energy conversion will lose some energy, some more than others. Using a string of conversions, a motor to crank the lever of a hydraulic system to lift a weight to run a generator might look impressive in a marble-run, but it's not an efficient way to convert energy.

If your initial motor turns the generator directly instead of operating the hydraulics, your losses will be lower.

If your intention is to close the loop, and once you have the efficiency high enough, harvest all of that promising free energy, then I'm afraid it will not work. If you manage to get 99% efficiency at every conversion, then it will take quite a long time to coast down after giving it an initial shove, without delivering any power. If you get a more realistic 50% per conversion, then it will come to a halt like a beanbag dropped on a carpet, without delivering any power.

Comment: Actually lifting the weight is compulsory for the rotation of the rotor and I am thinking to use the electricity produced by the alternator to be used for lifting purpose after storing the sufficient electricity into the supercapacitor and the direct the electricity for household purpose , does this makes the system a perpetual machine?

Comment: If your outputs are larger than your inputs, then it's a perpetual motion machine. Perhaps you'd care to draw a diagram of what you intend, and we can tell you why the detail won't work, rather than just telling you that the principle won't work.

Comment: Please specify what is meant by output and input in the above comment @Neil_UK

Comment: @tank12 You're building a system, of generators, motors, levers, hydraulics, supercap, generator etc etc. Draw a shell round that system, to isolate it from the outside world. 'Outputs' is energy drawn from that system, transmitted by electrical wires or a rotating shaft, of a pair of high pressure and low pressure hydraulic pipes. 'Inputs' is energy supplied to that system, perhaps by wires from a car battery under your desk, or a mains lead from the wall, or your hand turning some component round. Outputs and inputs are energy passing through the shell drawn round your 'system'.

Comment: So in my case the charging of super capacitor and the potential energy by the load suspended by the rotor will be input and the current produced by the alternator minus the current used to charge the capacitor will be the output. Am I right or not?@Neil_UK

Comment: @tank12 it doesn't sound like you're right according to my definitions. Are you supplying any input energy to your system from a wall socket? Are you using your system to provide an output to drive an external load like a lamp? All the energy circulating within your system stays within the system and is not input or output.

Comment: Well just like a dam where potential energy from the water is used to rotate the turbine in my case weight suspended from the rotor is playing that part and yes an external load will be provided the electricity generated@Neil_UK

Comment: please awnser the above comment

Comment: @tank12 Neil asked " Are you supplying any input energy to your system from a wall socket [or other source] ? " -> You did not answer. Unless there is an external energy source it will not run indefinitely

Comment: @tank12 I don't understand the above comment, it makes no sense to me at all. Please put a diagram into your original question of the sort of mechanical setup you envisage if you want to receive any useful replies.